# Python How to make a number triangle

Tags: python, numbers, triangle

So I've recently started learning python and my friend gave me a changllege. How to make a number triangle. So basically, I need to make python let me input a number, for example 5. After I do that, I want python to print

```
54321
4321
321
21
1
```

But because I am new to python, I don't know how to do it.
So far, I've got this:

```
x = int(input('Enter a Number: '))

for i in range(x,0,-1):
  print(i,end='')
  if i != 0:
    continue
  else:
    break
```

And the output is:

```
Enter a Number: 5
54321
```

Any ideas how to make it print
54321
4321
321
21
1
?
Thanks for any advice

Comment: You `break` on the first iteration. And additionally a `continue` as the effectively last command of the block makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code for you.

Short version (suggest learning about **list comprehension** and **join** functions):

```
x = int(input('Enter a Number: '))
for i in range(x, 0, -1):
    print(''.join([str(j) for j in range(i, 0, -1)]))
```

Longer version which is easier to understand:

```
for i in range(x, 0, -1):
    s = ''
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        s += str(j)
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
54321
4321
321
21
1
```

Comment: `[[print(i + 1, end=" ") if i < j else print() for i in reversed(range(j + 1))] for j in reversed(range(int(input("enter triangle number: ")) + 1))]` list comprehension :)

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = int(input("Inverted Right Triangle Numbers  = "))

print("Inverted")

for i in range(rows, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(j, end = ' ')
    print()
```

Output

```
5 4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 
3 2 1 
2 1 
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def trig_print(number):
    if number > 0:
        for i in range(number):
            print(number - i,end='')
        print('')
        number = number - 1
        trig_print(number)
    else:
        return 0

trig_print(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to solve it by while loop.

3 step

1. input initial number.
2. make list one to initial number.
3. reverse list and print it.

```py
>>> x = int(input('Enter a Number: '))
Enter a Number: 5
>>> while x >0 : 
    l=list(range(1,x+1)) # range function
    l.reverse()  # list.reverse function
    print(' '.join(map(str,l))) # join and map function
    # I recomanded input space between number for readability.
    x -= 1 
    
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
3 2 1
2 1
1
```